# how to stop this loop from repeating

Tags: python, loops

this was the mistake:

```py
while True:
    if french_grade == 1 and PE_grade == 1 and Math_grade == 1 and english_grade ==1:
        music grade == 0
```

and all i had to do to fix it was adding a `break` the line after music grade so it would stop the loop from repeating.

it should look like this:

```py
while True:
    if french_grade == 1 and PE_grade == 1 and Math_grade == 1 and english_grade ==1:
        music grade == 0
        break
```

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
You posted over 200 lines of code; this is excessive for the question you ask.

Comment: Your posted program hangs waiting for input.  Do not expect us to provide test data: simply replace your `input` with a test case that elicits the problem.

Comment: We also expect that you will trace the suspect values just before the point of error, and do your best to trace them back to their sources.. Where are you confused about how they got to those values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while True:
    if english_grade == 1 and math_grade == 1 and SocialStudies_grade == 1 and art_grade == 1 and science_grade == 1:
        french_Grade = 0
```

this runs forever ..setting `french=0`

you need to `break` the loop and other this kinds of loops too

Answer (score 0):

From code

```
if english_grade == 1 and math_grade == 1 and SocialStudies_grade == 1 and art_grade == 1 and science_grade == 1:
        french_Grade = 0
```

To code

```
elif english_grade == 1 and math_grade == 1 and SocialStudies_grade == 1 and art_grade == 1 and science_grade == 0 and PE_grade == 1:
        french_Grade = 0
```

From code

```
if english_grade == 1 and math_grade == 1 and SocialStudies_grade == 1 and art_grade == 1 and science_grade == 1:
            music_Grade = 0
```

To code

```
art_grade == 1 and science_grade == 1 and french_grade == 0 and PE_grade == 0:
                music_Grade = 0
```

You need to move the code outside the while loop.
And you didn't let the user entered PE Grade.